# Proving Y is a subspace of X and determining the dimension of Y.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I need help with two things. First, please confirm whether my proof below for part (i) is valid. Secondly, I'm not able to convince myself that the dimension of the subspace $Y$ described below is $n-j$. I know it has something to do with how we defined the elements of $Y$, but I cannot make the leap. Once I know how to do this, then part (iii) is easy to show.

---

Denote by $X$ the linear space of all polynomials $p(t)$ of degree less than $n$ and denote by $Y$ the set of polynomials that are zero at $t_1, \ldots, t_j$, $j<n$.

(i) Show that $Y$ is a subspace of $X$.

(ii) Determine the $\text{dim }Y$.

(iii) Determine $\text{dim }X/Y$.

---

(i)

Polynomials of degree less than $n$ that are zero at the points $t_1, \ldots, t_j$ can be expressed as

$$
q(t)\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i)
$$

where $q$ is a polynomial of degree less than $n-j$.

Let's denote $Y$ as $\{p(t) \in X : p(t) = 0, t = t_1, \ldots, t_j \}$.

To show that $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, we need to show the following:

(1) Closure under addition - If $p_1(t) \in Y$ and $p_2(t) \in Y$, then $p_1(t) + p_2(t) \in Y$.

(2) Closure under scalar multiplication - If $p_c(t) \in Y$, then $kp_c(t) \in Y$, $k \in \mathbf{F}$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is any field.

We omit showing $0 \in Y$ since it clearly is when $q(t)=0$.

Let $p_1(t) = q_1(t)\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i)$ and $p_2(t) = q_2(t)\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i)$ be any two polynomials in $Y$.

Thus,

$$
p_1(t) + p_2(t) = \left[q_1(t)+q_2(t)\right]\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i)
$$

For $t = t_1, \ldots, t_j$,

$$
p_1(t) + p_2(t) = 0 \implies \left[q_1(t)+q_2(t)\right]\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i) = 0
$$

where $q_1(t)+q_2(t)$ is a polynomial with degree less than $n-j$, which means

$$
\left[q_1(t)+q_2(t)\right]\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i) \in Y \implies p_1(t) + p_2(t) \in Y
$$

This shows closure under addition.

Next, suppose $p_c(t) = q_c(t)\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i) \in Y$.

For $t = t_1, \ldots, t_j$,

$$
p_c(t) = 0 \implies q_c(t)\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i) = 0
$$

For $k\in\mathbf{F}$,

$$
kq_c(t)\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i) = k0 = 0
$$

where $q_1(t)+q_2(t)$ is a polynomial with degree less than $n-j$, which means

$$
kq_c(t)\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_i) \in Y \implies kp_c(t) \in Y
$$

This shows closure under scalar multiplication.

Thus, $Y$ is a subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. We just need to establish a basis for $Y$, that is, we need to show that a set of polynomials $q_0(t), \ldots, q_{n-j-1}(t)$ are linearly independent and span $Y$, which would imply $\text{dim } Y = n-j$.

Let each polynomial $q_0(t), \ldots, q_{n-j-1}(t)$ be expressed as $q_w(t) = t^w$, where $w = 0, 1, \ldots, n-j-1$. Since each polynomial has different degree, they must be linearly independent. Also, for $p(t) \in Y$, we can write $p(t) = q(t)\prod_{i=1}^j(t-t_j)$ and express $q(t)$ as a linear combination of $q_0(t), \ldots, q_{n-j-1}(t)$, since it's degree $< n-j$. Thus, $q_0(t), \ldots, q_{n-j-1}(t)$ spans $Y$. By satisfying linear independence and span, we conclude that $q_0(t), \ldots, q_{n-j-1}(t)$ form a basis for $Y$, implying that the $\text{dim } Y = n-j$ since there are $(n-j-1)-0+1$ polynomials in the basis.